# Delete an array element in this foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach

I have this code wich I use in Wordpress for listing the tags and the number of times they've been used. Here is the code

```
<?php
$tags = get_tags( array('orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'DESC') );
foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) { ?>
<li class="list-group-item">
<span class="badge"><?php echo $tag->count; ?></span>
<?php echo $tag->name; ?>
</li>
<?php }
?>
```

The result is the following:

http://s14.postimg.org/z5qghdes1/result.png

So I want to delete the tag 'Animals' from the list. I've looking in other questions but I could not resolve my problem. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update your code as bellow:

```
<?php
$tags = get_tags( array('orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'DESC') );
foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) { 
  if ($tag->name == "Animals" ) { continue; }
?>
<li class="list-group-item">
<span class="badge"><?php echo $tag->count; ?></span>
<?php echo $tag->name; ?>
</li>
<?php }
?>
```

Comment: That works fine! In the other hand, how could I display only the tags I want? For example, I have a lot of tags but I only want to display 'Tech' and 'News'

Comment: @CristianTirado If you only want to display a certain set of tags you should use the include argument. See [Nathan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30283108/3250005), just use include instead of exclude.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `exclude` argument for `get_tags()`. In my example I set the term ID to 5; be sure to replace it with the correct value.

`exclude` can be an array as well allowing you to exclude multiple tags.

Change:

```
$tags = get_tags( array( 'orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
```

To:

```
$tags = get_tags( array( 
    'orderby' => 'count', 
    'order'   => 'DESC',
    'exclude' => 5,
) );
```

Comment: Given WordPress, this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use following

```
<?php
$tags = get_tags( array('orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'DESC') );
foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) { 
  if ($tag->name != "Animals" ) {
?>
<li class="list-group-item">
<span class="badge"><?php echo $tag->count; ?></span>
<?php echo $tag->name; ?>
</li>
<?php 
  }
}
?>
```